# generating indented attribute value with text

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need to transform an input xml into another xml, where it should print each element and if element has specific attribute (x or y) it should print value of it and the inline text. should happen for each element of input. As per the hierarchy of each element it should add indentation.

Input XML:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <root>
            <tom x="1" y="2" z='11'>
                <para x="3" y="4" z='22'>This is first para</para>
                <para x="5" y="6" z='23'>This is seond para
                    <ol x="7">
                        <li x="8" y="9" z='24'>this is listitem</li>
                        <li x="9" y="10" z='25'>this is listitem</li>
                    </ol>
                </para>
            </tom>
            <harry x='11' y='12'>
                <para x='13' y='14'>This is third para <b x='13'>this is bold <i y='14'>this is italic uder bold</i></b></para>
            </harry>
        </root>
```

Out put should be;

```
        <newXML>
        <p>{root}</p>
        <p>    {tom}</p>
        <p>   [Start attribute x='1']</p>
        <p>   [Start attribute y='2']</p>
        <p>       {para}</p>
        <p>       [Start attribute x='3']</p>
        <p>       [Start attribute y='4']</p>
        <p>         This is first para</p>
        <p>       [end attribute x='3']</p>
        <p>       [end attribute y='4']</p>
        <p>       {para}</p>
        <p>       [Start attribute x='5']</p>
        <p>       [Start attribute y='6']</p>
        <p>         This is second para</p>
        <p>          {ol}</p>
        <p>          [Start attribute x='7']</p>
        <p>            {li}</p>
        <p>            [Start attribute x='8']</p>
        <p>            [Start attribute y='9']</p>
        <p>              this is listitem</p>
        <p>            [end attribute x='8']</p>
        <p>            [end attribute y='9']</p>
        <p>            {li}</p>
        <p>             [Start attribute x='9']</p>
        <p>             [Start attribute y='10']</p>
        <p>              this is listitem</p>
        <p>             [end attribute x='9']</p>
        <p>             [end attribute y='10']</p>
        <p>         [end attribute x='7']</p>
        <p>       [end attribute x='5']</p>
        <p>       [end attribute y='6']</p>     
        <p>    [end attribute x='1']</p>
        <p>    [end attribute y='2']</p> 
        <p>   {harry}</p>
        <p>      ....</p>
        </newXML>
```

I am trying something like this, it fails for inline elements like 'ol', 'b', 'i'. Also not able to put indentation.

```
        <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
              <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:element name="newXML">
                  <xsl:for-each select="root//*">
                      <p>
                          <xsl:text>{</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/><xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
                      </p>
                      <xsl:if test="@x or @y">
                          <p><xsl:text>[Start attribute x=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@x"/><xsl:text>]</xsl:text></p>
                          <p><xsl:text>[Start attribute y=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@y"/><xsl:text>]</xsl:text></p>                                    
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:choose>
                          <xsl:when test="text()[1][(string-length(normalize-space(.)) = 0)]">
                              <p></p>
                          </xsl:when>
                          <xsl:otherwise>
                              <p>
                                  <xsl:apply-templates/>
                              </p>
                          </xsl:otherwise>
                      </xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:if test="@x or @y">
                          <p><xsl:text>[end attribute x=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@x"/><xsl:text>]</xsl:text></p>
                          <p><xsl:text>[end attribute y=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@y"/><xsl:text>]</xsl:text></p>                  
                      </xsl:if>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>        
            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template match="*">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="self::ol and parent::para"></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates></xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>        
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Phew. Can we work on a more simple example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an answer that differs from the other answers in that it actually uses XSLT/XPath 2.0 features such as a `for` loop, `xsl:function`, and a sequence. Since you can use 2.0, might as well take advantage of it!

Also, the attributes that should be included are done as an `xsl:param` and can be passed at runtime. No need to change hardcoded attribute names in the XSLT if your XML input changes.

**XML Input**

```
<root>
    <tom x="1" y="2" z='11'>
        <para x="3" y="4" z='22'>This is first para</para>
        <para x="5" y="6" z='23'>This is seond para
            <ol x="7">
                <li x="8" y="9" z='24'>this is listitem</li>
                <li x="9" y="10" z='25'>this is listitem</li>
            </ol>
        </para>
    </tom>
    <harry x='11' y='12'>
        <para x='13' y='14'>This is third para <b x='13'>this is bold <i y='14'>this is italic uder bold</i></b></para>
    </harry>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:l="local" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="l xs" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="include-attrs" select="('x','y')"/>

    <xsl:function name="l:indent">
        <xsl:param name="level"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to $level">
            <xsl:text>&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <newXML>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </newXML>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor-or-self::*)-1"/>      
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="l:indent($level)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('{',local-name(),'}')"/>
        </p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[local-name()=$include-attrs]">
            <xsl:with-param name="mode" select="'Start'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[local-name()=$include-attrs]">
            <xsl:with-param name="mode" select="'End'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:param name="mode"/>
        <xsl:param name="level"/>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="l:indent($level)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('[',$mode,' attribute ',local-name(),'=''',.,'''',']')"/>
        </p>    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor-or-self::*)"/>                
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="l:indent($level)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<newXML>
   <p>{root}</p>
   <p>    {tom}</p>
   <p>    [Start attribute x='1']</p>
   <p>    [Start attribute y='2']</p>
   <p>        {para}</p>
   <p>        [Start attribute x='3']</p>
   <p>        [Start attribute y='4']</p>
   <p>            This is first para</p>
   <p>        [End attribute x='3']</p>
   <p>        [End attribute y='4']</p>
   <p>        {para}</p>
   <p>        [Start attribute x='5']</p>
   <p>        [Start attribute y='6']</p>
   <p>            This is seond para</p>
   <p>            {ol}</p>
   <p>            [Start attribute x='7']</p>
   <p>                {li}</p>
   <p>                [Start attribute x='8']</p>
   <p>                [Start attribute y='9']</p>
   <p>                    this is listitem</p>
   <p>                [End attribute x='8']</p>
   <p>                [End attribute y='9']</p>
   <p>                {li}</p>
   <p>                [Start attribute x='9']</p>
   <p>                [Start attribute y='10']</p>
   <p>                    this is listitem</p>
   <p>                [End attribute x='9']</p>
   <p>                [End attribute y='10']</p>
   <p>            [End attribute x='7']</p>
   <p>        [End attribute x='5']</p>
   <p>        [End attribute y='6']</p>
   <p>    [End attribute x='1']</p>
   <p>    [End attribute y='2']</p>
   <p>    {harry}</p>
   <p>    [Start attribute x='11']</p>
   <p>    [Start attribute y='12']</p>
   <p>        {para}</p>
   <p>        [Start attribute x='13']</p>
   <p>        [Start attribute y='14']</p>
   <p>            This is third para</p>
   <p>            {b}</p>
   <p>            [Start attribute x='13']</p>
   <p>                this is bold</p>
   <p>                {i}</p>
   <p>                [Start attribute y='14']</p>
   <p>                    this is italic uder bold</p>
   <p>                [End attribute y='14']</p>
   <p>            [End attribute x='13']</p>
   <p>        [End attribute x='13']</p>
   <p>        [End attribute y='14']</p>
   <p>    [End attribute x='11']</p>
   <p>    [End attribute y='12']</p>
</newXML>
```

Comment: This is cool. Thank you Daniel, this is best fit solution for my problem. The issue was with earlier solutions posted, it does not take care of inline text  for ex. **<p> this is para <b>this is bold</b> this is rest of para</p>**. note: the text "this is rest of para" appear directly after "this is para".. I know i dint added this scenario in my input xml. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Phew indeed. I will put the indentation issue aside for the moment and ask you to examine the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
<newXML>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</newXML>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <p>
          <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/>
          <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </p>

    <xsl:if test="@x">
        <p>
            <xsl:text>[Start attribute x=</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@x"/>
            <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
        </p>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@y">
        <p>
            <xsl:text>[Start attribute y=</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@y"/>
            <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
        </p>                                    
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:variable name="mytext" select="normalize-space(./text())" />
    <xsl:if test="$mytext">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="$mytext"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:if>   

    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>

    <xsl:if test="@x">
        <p>
            <xsl:text>[end attribute x=</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@x"/>
            <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
        </p>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@y">
        <p>
            <xsl:text>[end attribute y=</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@y"/>
            <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
        </p>                  
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using your example input, the following output is produced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<newXML>
  <p>{tom}</p>
  <p>[Start attribute x=1]</p>
  <p>[Start attribute y=2]</p>
  <p>{para}</p>
  <p>[Start attribute x=3]</p>
  <p>[Start attribute y=4]</p>
  <p>This is first para</p>
  <p>[end attribute x=3]</p>
  <p>[end attribute y=4]</p>
  <p>{para}</p>
  <p>[Start attribute x=5]</p>
  <p>[Start attribute y=6]</p>
  <p>This is seond para</p>
  <p>{ol}</p>
  <p>[Start attribute x=7]</p>
  <p>{li}</p>
  <p>[Start attribute x=8]</p>
  <p>[Start attribute y=9]</p>
  <p>this is listitem</p>
  <p>[end attribute x=8]</p>
  <p>[end attribute y=9]</p>
  <p>{li}</p>
  <p>[Start attribute x=9]</p>
  <p>[Start attribute y=10]</p>
  <p>this is listitem</p>
  <p>[end attribute x=9]</p>
  <p>[end attribute y=10]</p>
  <p>[end attribute x=7]</p>
  <p>[end attribute x=5]</p>
  <p>[end attribute y=6]</p>
  <p>[end attribute x=1]</p>
  <p>[end attribute y=2]</p>
  <p>{harry}</p>
  <p>[Start attribute x=11]</p>
  <p>[Start attribute y=12]</p>
  <p>{para}</p>
  <p>[Start attribute x=13]</p>
  <p>[Start attribute y=14]</p>
  <p>This is third para</p>
  <p>{b}</p>
  <p>[Start attribute x=13]</p>
  <p>this is bold</p>
  <p>{i}</p>
  <p>[Start attribute y=14]</p>
  <p>this is italic uder bold</p>
  <p>[end attribute y=14]</p>
  <p>[end attribute x=13]</p>
  <p>[end attribute x=13]</p>
  <p>[end attribute y=14]</p>
  <p>[end attribute x=11]</p>
  <p>[end attribute y=12]</p>
</newXML>
```

If this is satisfactory, we can discuss the indentation next.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <newXML>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </newXML>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <p>{<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>}</p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[local-name() = 'x' or local-name() = 'y']" mode='start'/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::text()[normalize-space(.) != '']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[local-name() = 'x' or local-name() = 'y']" mode='end'/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*[local-name() = 'x' or local-name() = 'y']" mode='start'>
    <p>[Start attribute x ='<xsl:value-of select="."/>']</p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*[local-name() = 'x' or local-name() = 'y']" mode='end'>
    <p>[end attribute x ='<xsl:value-of select="."/>']</p>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space(.)!='']">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></p>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="concat('{', name(), '}')"/></p>
        <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/child::*">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;', '{', name(), '}')"/></p>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position()!=3">
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;', '[Start attribute ', name(), '=', '&quot;', ., '&quot;', ']')"/></p>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/child::*/child::*">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;&#x9;', '{', name(), '}')"/></p>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position()!=3">
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;&#x9;', '[Start attribute ', name(), '=', '&quot;', ., '&quot;', ']')"/></p>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/child::*/child::*/text()">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;', normalize-space(.))"/></p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/child::*/child::*/child::*">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;', '{', name(), '}')"/></p>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <p><xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;', '[Start attribute ', name(), '=', '&quot;', ., '&quot;', ']')"/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/child::*/child::*/child::*/text()">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;', normalize-space(.))"/></p>    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/child::*/child::*/child::*/child::*">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;', '{', name(), '}')"/></p>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position()!=3">
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;', '[Start attribute ', name(), '=', '&quot;', ., '&quot;', ']')"/></p>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/child::*/child::*/child::*/child::*/text()">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;', normalize-space(.))"/></p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```